# angular route resolve - wait on value to be defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plotly, ngroute

I wrote a wrapper to load/unload javascript and css for routes conditionally. It is called in the route resolve section like:

```
resolve: {
    factory: function (Res) {
        controllersAndServices(Res, {styles: 'estilos/check_insurance.css'})
    }
}
```

It it generally works like a charm. Problem is, some libraries, like Plotly defer creating their main variable, so the library loads before it is avaialable. As a result, I get errors that Plotly is not defined in my controller, then later, they go away. *definitely* by the time I get to the console, Plotly is happily waiting for me.

I do realize that this problably could happen to a lot more libraries with my custom loader, but happily most are too small to have this problem. plotly is both large and can take many hundreds or even thousands of milliseconds to set up.

So I need to wait on Plotly being defined in my `resolve`, somehow. How do you do that?

Library:

#### res_service.js

```
angular.module('app').service('Res', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var scope = $rootScope
    scope._scripts = scope._scripts || []
    scope._styles = scope._styles || []
    scope._rawScripts = scope._rawScripts || []
    scope._rawStyles = scope._rawStyles || []

    return {
        style: function (inp) {
            var hrefs = []
            if (typeof inp === 'string') {
                hrefs.push(inp)
            } else {
                hrefs = inp
            }

            scope._styles = []
            for (var i in hrefs) {
                console.log('styling page with ' + hrefs[i])
                var style = document.createElement('link')
                if (!/^https?\:\/\//.test(hrefs[i])) {
                    style.type = 'text/css'
                }
                style.href = hrefs[i]
                style.rel = 'stylesheet'

                if (scope._rawStyles === undefined) {
                    scope._rawStyles = []
                }
                scope._rawStyles.push([hrefs[i], style])
                scope._styles.push(document.head.appendChild(style))

                scope.$on('$destroy', this.clean_styles)
            }
        },

        clean_styles: function () {
            var removables = []
            for (var key in scope._rawStyles) {
                console.log('deleting style ' + scope._rawStyles[key][0])
                scope._styles[key].parentNode.removeChild(scope._rawStyles[key][1])
                removables.push(key)
            }

            scope._styles = scope._styles.filter(function (v) { return (removables.indexOf(v) !== -1)? true: false })
            scope._rawStyles = scope._rawStyles.filter(function (v) { return (removables.indexOf(v) !== -1)? true: false })
        },

        script: function (inp) {
            var hrefs = []
            if (typeof inp === 'string') {
                hrefs.push(inp)
            } else {
                hrefs = inp
            }

            scope._scripts = []
            for (var i in hrefs) {
                console.log('loading javascript: ' + hrefs[i])
                var script = document.createElement('script')
                if (!/^https?\:\/\//.test(hrefs[i])) {
                    script.type = 'text/javascript'
                }
                script.src = hrefs[i]

                if (scope._rawScripts === undefined) {
                    scope._rawScripts = []
                }
                scope._rawScripts.push([hrefs[i], script])
                scope._scripts.push(document.head.appendChild(script))

                scope.$on('$destroy', this.clean_scripts)
            }
        },

        clean_scripts: function () {
            var removables = []
            for (var key in scope._rawScripts) {
                console.log('deleting script ' + scope._rawScripts[key][0])
                scope._scripts[key].parentNode.removeChild(scope._rawScripts[key][1])
                removables.push(key)
            }

            scope._scripts = scope._scripts.filter(function (v) { return (removables.indexOf(v) !== -1)? true: false })
            scope._rawScripts = scope._rawScripts.filter(function (v) { return (removables.indexOf(v) !== -1)? true: false })
        }

    }
}])
```

example breaking route usage:

#### route.js

```
...
                when('/', {
                    templateUrl: 'hipermídia/check_insurance.template.html',
                    controller: 'pedidos_controller',
                    resolve: {
                        factory: function (Res) {
                            controllersAndServices(Res, {scripts: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'})
                        }
                    }
                }).
```

At this point, if you use plotly in your controller like:

```
var data = [
  {
    x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y: [20, 14, 23],
    type: 'bar'
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('myDivID', data);
```

You'll likely get something like `ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined`.
If you move it back aways, with a synchronous calls, maybe a setTimeout, or even just angular's document ready, the likelyhood of seeing a a proper graph will increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit hacky, but I would loop/test if the `Plotly` var exists in a root route from which every route that need the library is a child of (the resolve is applied to child routes if they inject the property as well).

something like the following would be resolved in the root route:

```js
resolve: {
    plotly: function () {
        const resolvePlotly = function () {
          while (typeOf Plotly) === 'undefined') {
            return setTimeout(function () { resolvePlotly() }, 150)
          }
          return Plotly
        }

        return resolvePlotly()
    }
}
```

I'd add that resolved injection to that route, and pass it down to the child routes so the dependency would still wait for the `Plotly` object to be defined before running any dependent controller.

You could also write a factory wrapping the `Plotly` object that returns it when available, and inject/use it instead of directly accessing `Plotly`.

Comment: Of the options you listed, I like the resolve method best, because it keeps it generic. Factories would be one-offs. That code is bad though, could you rewrite it so it works (maybe make a [//plunker.co](//plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) out of it? Here's a skeleton from what I interpreted as your answer: http://plnkr.co/edit/odTwpk

Comment: nvm, got it now: http://plnkr.co/edit/8c7pha?p=preview -- the psuedo code you have needs to be rewritten. To be helpful to others, you might consider reviewing my plunker and updating yur answer.

Comment: Just saw your comments, glad you figured it out! I will edit shortly.